# String[] Constant Sorts Automatically? How do I keep index order?

Tags: java, arrays

I have  String[] of delimiters

```
private static final String[] LEFT_DELIMITER = {
    "PUT", "CALL",
    "JAN", "FEB", "MAR", "APR", "MAY", "JUN", 
    "JUL", "AUG", "SEP", "OCT", "NOV", "DEC"
};
```

When I loop through this String[] with a good old for loop the entry at index 0 is JAN and not PUT. However, if I declare the String[] within the method where I am using it

```
String[] delim = {
    "PUT", "CALL",
    "JAN", "FEB", "MAR", "APR", "MAY", "JUN", 
    "JUL", "AUG", "SEP", "OCT", "NOV", "DEC"
};
```

The result at index 0 is PUT as expected.

Why does one sort by calendar month and the other does not? All I want is for the array to maintain items where I put them. Is there a way to do that as a constant?

Comment: Can't reproduce that problem...

Comment: Post the entire loop. What you're describing is unexpected to say the least.

Comment: ^ same here. It works fine for me, JDK 1.7 IntelliJ.

Comment: It shouldn't if you are just using basic for loop without other operations. Can you provide more code?

Comment: Post the entire code please. I cant reproduce.

Comment: Arrays are not automatically sorted. Your description of what you have done must be wrong. Post the code.

Comment: Maybe it's because the array is less `final` than you expect? `LEFT_DELIMITER[0]="whatever";` is not forbidden!

Comment: Very unexpected - I've never see this before either which is why its crazy. Arrays do not self order. No idea why that's happening.

Comment: @ammoQ I think you're closest I suspect something else is modifying the the array. That's why the one inside the method is different. That's what you get for setting non-final things as final.

Comment: BTW, sorting would put APR first, not JAN.

Comment: Either way I can vote to close the question since the issue I suspect is something else

Answer (score 1):

I don't think so. I was really shocked when I read the question, but a quick unit test proved that indeed everything is ok.

```
import org.junit.Assert;

public class Test {

    private static final String[] LEFT_DELIMITER = {
            "PUT", "CALL",
            "JAN", "FEB", "MAR", "APR", "MAY", "JUN",
            "JUL", "AUG", "SEP", "OCT", "NOV", "DEC"
    };

    @org.junit.Test
    public void test() {
        String[] delim = {
                "PUT", "CALL",
                "JAN", "FEB", "MAR", "APR", "MAY", "JUN",
                "JUL", "AUG", "SEP", "OCT", "NOV", "DEC"
        };

        for (int i = 0; i < LEFT_DELIMITER.length; i++) {
            Assert.assertEquals(LEFT_DELIMITER[i], delim[i]);
        }
    }
}
```

Are you 100% sure that the code you wrote ends up in your compiled class files? I would assume that you think you run a certain code, but indeed run something different - an old version perhaps?

Comment: That's a good suggestion, let me check on that.

Comment: I think I found the issue - some other part of code is modifying array and since array is not final it gets changed. That's why the local copy stays in order because it cannot be reached.